# Google Translate, languages, and numbers oh my!

Tags: discussion, languages, translations

I don't expect Stack Exchange to strong arm Google into changing Google Translate, but I did want to bring this to your attention, and suggest that a short investigation might be worthwhile to find out if something can be done on Stack Exchange's side to make Google Translate work better.

If you use Google Translate to translate, for example, [this Spanish page](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-las-funciones-de-inicio-de-jquery) into [English](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444/cu%25C3%25A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-las-funciones-de-inicio-de-jquery&usg=ALkJrhiTOm04fRIguzOBHRXhzlKVujd0IQ), you find that Google sometimes converts the vote counts to named items, not always numbers.  So far I've found the following:

- 0 --> 0
- 1 --> one
- 2 --> 2
- 3 --> three
- 4 --> four
- 5 --> May
- 6 --> June or six
- 7 --> seven

Given that the numbers are perfectly valid as-is in English, there's no need for Google to upgrade them to text at all, never mind choosing to alter some, not others, and occasionally changing one to a date rather than a number.

How is Stack Exchange presenting that data that would cause Google Translate to treat these numbers as something that should be translated into something other than numbers?

Comment: You can suggest changes in Google Translate. If enough people go through changing back, maybe the Bayesian (or whatever it is) algorithm will get retrained?

Comment: @Benjol Yes, and I've done it a few times on that site to see if things would change quickly.  Perhaps if enough people do it, that would be sufficient.

Comment: I suggest we change all the numbers to custom images of unicorns holding the numbers. This will fix the problem.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist That's the ideal solution! To the [balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) signal!

Answer (score 4):

This can be fixed by using [`translate="no"`](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-translate-flag) on the container for each number:

```html
<span class="badgecount" translate="no">41</span>
```

This would affect translation to any language, not just English.

While some languages like Japanese have number systems of their own, I'm not aware of any that don't use our number system at all. For reference, see an [example post on Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41558/ls-a-%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c-%e3%82%84-%e3%82%92%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86/41566#41566): the top scoring answer has a score of "11" when not translated, and "11 11" when translated to English.

Comment: Perhaps this would have a better chance if posted as a separate [feature-request].