# Badges forgot how to count

Tags: bug, design, badges

When reading a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379274/closing-as-duplicate-produces-a-comment-with-broken-markdown-and-link-if-the-qu) here on MSE just yet, I noticed this. Instead of the number 15, the badge count is written as a word.

[image]

I haven't found any other instance that replicates this.

Comment: This happens when my browser auto translates the page to English for me on non-English SE sites. Is your browser doing that for you mistakenly on that page?

Comment: @Spevacus that must have been automatic or in some sneaky way on Chrome then, cause I haven't set anythung like that up.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the page is automatically or manually translated to English. Since there was Russian text in the question you linked, Google [gave me an option to switch between translations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qbd3.png). After translating to English, the result was the same as in your case:

[image]

[image]

This has been a known issue on non-English sites. For example, see: [Vietnamese to English translation issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361994/vietnamese-to-english-translation-issue) and [Google Translate, languages, and numbers oh my!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272536/google-translate-languages-and-numbers-oh-my). This is not an issue from SE's side, but from Google's side. See: ["Numbers translated into words (undesired)" on Google Translate Help Community](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/28230365/numbers-translated-into-words-undesired).

Comment: Yeah I recall that indeed. I however have never seen google translate anything for me on mobile Chrome. So perhaps I just missed it this time?

Comment: @Luuklag: On PC, there's an option to automatically translate Russian to English: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFOv2.png ["Always translate Russian"]

Comment: @Luuklag: Have a look at [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/215103) on mobile Chrome. When you translate to English for the first time, you get a message (basically) saying that Russian text will be automatically translated to English from now on (this is the *automatic* translation I was talking about).

Comment: It is possible that you might have missed it, because this is specifically a translation issue, and cannot be reproduced otherwise.